# How to create a calculation based on end result?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make an application which makes calculations as strings based on the end result, it does not calculate them, but it creates them. A simple example: x + x = 10. Then it needs to generate all possible solutions like 3 + 7, 4 + 6 and so on, in an array or list.

I'm sorry if this doesn't make sense. It's translated from danish and there's some language barriers that I can't find words for on English.

I've tried to take the result, lets say 10, subtracted a random number between 1 and the result(which was 10), lets say 4, and after that put it in a string like so: (10 - 4) + 4 = 6 + 4 = 10.

```cs
int result = 10;
double random = Random.Range(1, result);
double firstNumber = result - (int)random;

answer = firstNumber.ToString() + "+" + random.ToString();
```

It outputs the right results, but it is very limited. At the same time i need it to change the random range, so it never ends at something like 1999 + 1 = 2000, but more like 1850 + 150 = 2000.
Maybe in the future also add more +'es and -'es.

So is there any much simpler solution, or a math equation that I've not heard of?

Comment: You want just any arbitrary pair of numbers that sum up to 2000? Or all possible combinations? Anyway I don´t get what you mean by "so it never ends at something like 1999 + 1 = 2000, but more like 1850 + 150 = 2000". You may get up to 2000 repetitions (and even more) to get something in the range of 19xx and xx.

Comment: But I don´t see much you can do here. Maybe - if some day you have more operators - yiu may use a recursive function, that adds a random number and calls itself again with the rest until the rest is zero.

Comment: It's for creating calculations that has to be calculated in the head fast, but they don't need to be to simple (hence not the 1999 + 1), so in the Random.Range(x, result), x has to increase a small amount of the result, so x can't be 1 but rather 100.

Comment: Then why not using a random between e.g. 1 and 90% of the total? So in case of total being 2000, you create a random number between 1 and 1800.

Comment: Yes, that could be possible, and maybe I also could add maybe 10-20% of the result, at the start like 10% to 90%?

Comment: So you produce a number between 200 and 1800? Sure, why not. That actually makes more sense, because if your random-number was 1, you´d had the same simplicity you want to avoid (1999 + 1 = 1 + 1999). So actually you want to strip numbers on both sides.

Comment: I'll test it right away now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With two numbers it´s just about creating a random number in a decent range. So let´s say you want to avoid the trivial combinations like 1 + 1999 up tp 10 + 1990. As adding numbers is permutable (1 + 1999 is the same as 1999 + 1), you need random numbers "in the middle", e.g. from 10 to 1990. You can even make this more flexibe depending on your total number:

```
var total = 2000;
var minFactor = 0.1, maxFactor = 0.9;
var r = Random.Range(minFactor * total, maxFactor * total);
```

This creates numbers between 200 and 1800.

The rest is pretty straight-forward - which you already have:

```
var secondNumber = result - r;
```

When you have more numbers you best use some recurive function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version.

```
private static int[] GetEquation(uint endResult, int n, double range, bool allowBelowZero, Random rnd)
{
    var numbers = new int[n];
    do
    {
        var sum = (int) endResult;
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        {
            do
            {
                var plusMinus = (i == 0) ? true : rnd.Next(0, 100) < 50;
                var upper = Math.Max(Math.Abs(sum), Math.Abs((int)endResult));
                var x = (int)(1 + (rnd.Next(1, upper + 1)));
                numbers[i] = plusMinus ? x : 0 - x;
            } while ((!allowBelowZero && (sum - numbers[i] > endResult)) || (Math.Abs(numbers[i]) > Math.Abs(endResult)));
            sum -= numbers[i];
        }
        numbers[numbers.Length - 1] = sum;
    } while (numbers.Any(x => (Math.Abs(x) > (Math.Abs(endResult) * range)) || x == 0));
    return numbers;
}
```

## Test

### Code

```
public static void Main()
{
    uint endResult = 10;
    var range = 0.75;

    foreach (var n in new[] { 3, 4, 5, 10})
        foreach (var allowBelowZero in new[] { false, true })
            for (int seed = 0; seed < 3; seed++)
            {
                var rnd = new Random(seed); // Fixed seed;
                var numbers = GetEquation(endResult, n, range, allowBelowZero, rnd);
                Print(endResult, n, allowBelowZero, seed, numbers);
            }
}

private static void Print(uint endResult, int n, bool allowBelowZero, int seed, int[] numbers)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i > 0 && numbers[i] >= 0) sb.Append("+");
        sb.Append(numbers[i]);
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"(n={n}, seed={seed}, 'allow <0'={allowBelowZero}): {endResult}={sb.ToString()}");
}
```

### Output

```
// .NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0
(n=3, seed=0, 'allow <0'=False): 10=7+7-4
(n=3, seed=1, 'allow <0'=False): 10=7-4+7
(n=3, seed=2, 'allow <0'=False): 10=6+2+2
(n=3, seed=0, 'allow <0'=True): 10=7+7-4
(n=3, seed=1, 'allow <0'=True): 10=6-2+6
(n=3, seed=2, 'allow <0'=True): 10=6+2+2
(n=4, seed=0, 'allow <0'=False): 10=6-6+6+4
(n=4, seed=1, 'allow <0'=False): 10=5-4+3+6
(n=4, seed=2, 'allow <0'=False): 10=5+2-2+5
(n=4, seed=0, 'allow <0'=True): 10=2+3+3+2
(n=4, seed=1, 'allow <0'=True): 10=7+5-5+3
(n=4, seed=2, 'allow <0'=True): 10=2+4+6-2
(n=5, seed=0, 'allow <0'=False): 10=7-3+3+6-3
(n=5, seed=1, 'allow <0'=False): 10=4+7+5-5-1
(n=5, seed=2, 'allow <0'=False): 10=6+2-2+7-3
(n=5, seed=0, 'allow <0'=True): 10=3-5+3+6+3
(n=5, seed=1, 'allow <0'=True): 10=5+3+6-3-1
(n=5, seed=2, 'allow <0'=True): 10=6+2-2+7-3
(n=10, seed=0, 'allow <0'=False): 10=7-2+6+3-2+2-7-4+3+4
(n=10, seed=1, 'allow <0'=False): 10=2+2+6-3+5-4-5+4+7-4
(n=10, seed=2, 'allow <0'=False): 10=2+5+3-6+4+5+2-7-2+4
(n=10, seed=0, 'allow <0'=True): 10=5-5+5-2-6-4+7-2+7+5
(n=10, seed=1, 'allow <0'=True): 10=2+2+4+6-5+3-6-2+3+3
(n=10, seed=2, 'allow <0'=True): 10=3-7-6+7+4-5-5+7+5+7
```

Comment: It looks like something that might work, but I'm not experienced enough to understand it. Can you give a little explanation?